# ERROR:CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Here I am trying to enter the details as follows and then it needs to be retrieved.

```
package com.example.orderform;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewActivity extends Activity{

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
  }
  public void onClick(View V) {
    Cursor c1=null;

    final SQLiteDatabase db;

    db=openOrCreateDatabase("Order", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    db.execSQL("Create Table if not exists codeo(name Varchar,Address Varchar,code int(10),password int(10),phno int(10),email Varchar,ccode int(10));");

    final String name;
    final String Address;
    final String code;
    final String ccode;
    final String password;
    final String phno;
    final String email;
    final EditText n=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText c2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText a=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final EditText em=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    final EditText ph=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    final EditText cc=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    final EditText pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);

    name=n.getText().toString();
    code=c2.getText().toString();
    Address=a.getText().toString();
    phno=ph.getText().toString();
    email=em.getText().toString();
    ccode=cc.getText().toString();
    password=pass.getText().toString();
    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("")||code.equalsIgnoreCase("")||ccode.equalsIgnoreCase("")||password.equalsIgnoreCase("")||Address.equalsIgnoreCase("")||phno.equalsIgnoreCase("")||email.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Field Can be Left Blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
      if(code.equals(ccode))
      {
        try
        {

          c1=db.rawQuery("Select * from codeo where code='"+code+"'", null);
          c1.moveToFirst();

          if(c1.getCount()<=0)
          {
            try
            {
              AlertDialog.Builder alrt=new AlertDialog.Builder(NewActivity.this);
              alrt.setTitle("CONFIRMATION");
              alrt.setCancelable(false);
              alrt.setMessage("Are You Sure that no more Changes on the above details");
              alrt.setPositiveButton("YES",new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  try
              {
                db.execSQL("Insert into codeo values('"+name+"','"+code+"','"+ccode+"','"+Address+"','"+phno+"','"+email+"','"+password+"');");
                n.setText("");
                c2.setText("");
                pass.setText("");
                a.setText("");
                ph.setText("");
                em.setText("");
                cc.setText("");
                SharedPreferences sp= getSharedPreferences("My code",0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor e=sp.edit();
                e.putString("code1",code);
                /*e.putString("Address",Address);
                  e.putString("name",name);
                  e.putString("email", email);
                  e.putString("ccode",ccode);
                  e.putString("phno",phno);
                  e.putString("password",password);
                  e.putString("code",code);*/
                e.commit();
                Intent j=new Intent(getBaseContext(), New1Activity.class);
                startActivity(j);
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
                }
              });
              alrt.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  dialog.cancel();
                }
              });
              AlertDialog al=   alrt.create();
              al.show();

            }
            catch(Exception er)
            {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception in getcount", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          }
          else
          {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

        }
        catch(Exception er)
        {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception in isfirst", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      }
      else
      {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code and Confirm Code doesn't Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        c2.setText("");
        cc.setText("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to retrieve the data.But i am getting CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException Index 0 requested, with a size of 0.

```
package com.example.orderform;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class New1Activity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new1);


    String name,Address,code,phno,email,ccode,password;
    Cursor c;

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("NewActivity", 0);

    name=sp.getString("name", "");   

    code=sp.getString("code", "");   

    Address=sp.getString("Address", "");



    phno=sp.getString("phno", "");

    email=sp.getString("email","");

    ccode=sp.getString("ccode", "");

    password=sp.getString("password", "");

    db=openOrCreateDatabase("Order", MODE_MULTI_PROCESS, null); 

    db.execSQL("Create Table if not exists codeo(name Varchar,Address Varchar,code 

      int(10),password int(10),phno int(10),email Varchar,ccode int(10));");

    c=db.rawQuery("Select * from codeo where code='"+code+"'", null); 

    c.moveToFirst();
    name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));

    code=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("code"));

    Address=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Address"));

    phno=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("phno"));
    email=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("email"));
    ccode=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ccode"));
    password=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("password"));




    TextView n=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);

    n.setText(name);

    TextView c2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);

    c2.setText(code);

    TextView a=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);

    a.setText(Address);

    TextView em=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);

    em.setText(email);

    TextView ph=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);

    ph.setText(phno);

    TextView cc=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);

    cc.setText(ccode);

    TextView pass=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);

    pass.setText(password);

  }
  public void onClick(View view)
  {
    startActivity(new Intent(this,CodeActivity.class));
  }


}
```

Comment: And format your code before pasting it here. I've done as much as my time allow me, but it is still poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PROBLEM :- your cursor array do not contain any data in this case, in other words its `empty`
```

You **cant request** the `index o` if `size` of the

```
cursor array is 0
```

As if you remember the

```
indexes start from zero in array..
```

so when actually `you request 0 index` it actually `means you are requesting first element of the cursor array`.

which `further means that cursor array contains at least one element` at `index zero`.

which `further derives that size of cursor array is not zero` in this case.

SO YOU NEED TO add some condition in when you are requesting the cursor array that `if the size is 0` then it `should skip` that condition

Refer this image

when you will `request index 0` here in this image it `will be 23`.

but `if the size of the cursor array will be zero` then you `cant request the 0 index`..

here `size of array is 6`

and but `indexes of array are in the range of 0-5`

[image: Array indexing]